# .click() event when 'Open in new tab/window'

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use `.click()` on an `<a>` tag, the event only works when I click on the element.  Otherwise, if the user does a Right Click > Open in new window or Open in new tab, it doesn't trigger the `click()` event.

So, my question is...how do I trigger the `click()` event when user does right click > open in new tab/window?

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="url">Click Me</a>
```

Here is the Js:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

Comment: ummm.. thats only a right click, not `open in new window/tab`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The only way I see is to catch mouse right button click and trigger `click` event manually.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I think one of the reason is that you don't want the website to be able to track the external link you are visiting.

Comment: ok well i think i guess i will just have to use that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code, but remember that changing the UI is not a good ideia:

```
var addEvent = (document.addEventListener) ?
    function(target,event,fn){
        if(target) return target.addEventListener(event,fn,false);
    }:
    function(target,event,fn){
        if(target) return target.attachEvent(('on' + event),fn);
    },
allLinks = document.links || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++)
    addEvent(allLinks[i],'mouseup',function(e){
        var e = e  || event;
        if(e.which===3){
            alert('Open in new tab/window');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This looks like it considers all right clicks to be an "open in new tab" event.