# How to disable or hide the Open In New Tab option for hyperlinks

Tags: javascript

On hyperlinks in the right click menu, how can I remove or hide the *Open In New Tab* and *Open In New Window* options?

for example

```
<a href="#" onclick="asd">foo</a>
```

Comment: You can not remove that. Enjoy telling that to your boss/client.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/

Comment: then how I call onclick method through right click->open in new tab on hyperlink

Comment: For onclick see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774151/click-event-when-open-in-new-tab-window

Comment: You can not detect if someone clicks on an option in the context menu. It is an impossible task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable right click on my web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: You can do that. Perfect example is this german newspaper: http://www.sueddeutsche.de/ There are links on the headings and also on the abstracts. But "open in new tab/window" is disabled on the abstract. Very annoying.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure why you'd want to do this but it can be done by moving the `href` to a `data-href` attribute, then remove the `href` and add a click handler. The onclick will read the `data-href` and redirect.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CC9JH/)

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].setAttribute("data-href", links[i].getAttribute("href"));
    links[i].removeAttribute("href");
    links[i].onclick = function(){
        window.location = this.getAttribute("data-href");
    };
}
```

The right click menu shows:

[image]

Comment: This is the cleanest option, I concur with Mr Code

Comment: I just googled to this.  The reason i'd want to do it is that i have links set up which trigger an ajax action in a modal, and if the user opens them in a new tab then it breaks it (since it's in a new window rather than the modal and doesn't have all the context it needs).  Taking the href off is the best solution, i think: i will need to add some extra styling to make them look like links again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript link instead of plain html ones. Just do href="javascript:void(0)" and handle the click event to redirect the page. This won't remove the option of opening in another tab but will make sure the page doesn't actually open up when tried.

Also instead of an HTML  tag, you can instead use another tag like  and give it a cursor:pointer css property and jquery onclick to make it work like a link. This will completely remove the option "open in another tab" from context menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using following code.

```
<script language="javascript">
$("a").click(function(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     return false;    
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by event.button==2 here ?. Can you please explain I am also trying to stop a link from opening into new tab/window

Comment: Button 2 stands for second click of the mouse.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but it should be if(event.which==2)
event.which == 1 left click
event.which == 2 middle roller click
event.which == 3 right click..

I think event.button ==2 for right click from jquery