# Bootstrap modal: disable opening in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/154/).

**Question:** How to disable opening `Home` and `Profile` tabs in new window?

Comment: Did you try removing the `data-toggle` arguments?

Comment: @Lawrence yes, no result.

Comment: Then it is most likely defined in the CSS for `nav nav-tabs`. Please attach the CSS *relevant* contents.

Comment: @Lawrence look at additional section of my question. I've posted the whole css.

Comment: Hm, i can't reproduce the issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNuv4/). There could be some JS code on the page that is doing this?

Comment: @Lawrence reproduce what? I want change standard bootstrap behavior.

Comment: could you please, explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? I couldn't actually capture it even after I've gone through entire discussion.

Comment: @code-jaff I use twitter-bootstrap. That means I can set special classes to my html-elements and they'll be displayed as popups, tabs, dialogs etc. If I want tabs inside dialog I should use `li` element with `a` inside. Now I want to prevent user open those `a` reference in new tab.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Ok, what actually confuses was, you mean by tab is browser tab or bootstrap tab?

Comment: @code-jaff I mean both ). Bootstrap displays `a` references as dialog tabs; I want to disable opening those bootstrap-tabs in new BROWSER tab

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk As far as I know you cannot prevent that. This sounds like how to prevent a browser from going to a particular URL.

Comment: @code-jaff actually the question is "how to intercept `go to new tab` event?". Is that impossible?

Comment: @code-jaff look at upgraded question with demo please

Comment: @Lawrence look at upgraded question with demo please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple: add oncontextmenu="return false;" to the ul element.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home Tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the links from doing anything:

```
$('#view-modal-nav a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //handle your code here
});
```

Comment: I want they work. The problem is that I have SPA with single entry point. I mean to open some url, user must go through home-page. So I should disable opening links in new tab/window.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk You can handle that in the javascript function. I'm not sure if there is any other way to disable opening links in a new tab/window.

Comment: how? I know how to intercept event. How can I distinguish whether user is gonna open link in the same tab or new one?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk You can check if the user is going to middle mouse with the event object. If you want to disable open in new link on right click, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169198/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-open-in-new-tab-option-for-hyperlinks . You might have to do both

Comment: look at upgraded question with demo please

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$('#view-modal-nav a').click(function (e) {   
       e.preventDefault(); //Prevents Opening of Links
       $(this).tab('show'); //Shows the Corresponding tab
});
```

Comment: that doesn't intercept `open in new tab` event.

Comment: look at upgraded question with demo please