# How does one prevent the opening of a new tab or window when hyperlink behavior was created virtually by e.g. an HTML button's "click" event handling?

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, dom-events, event-bubbling

I can disable opening new tab or window in case of `<a>` tag by removing `target` attribute e.g. `target='_blank'`

In some cases instead of `<a>` website put `<button>` and add `onClick()` or `submit()` etc which programmatically generates a link and sets the `target` attribute.

```html
<button id="653cde4c-1620-11ec-85b5-5ae26c154b46">
    <div>click here</div>
</button>
```

In some [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) generated javascript file there would be something like which would not be easy to find and read minified code.

```js
var button = document.querySelctor('653cde4c-1620-11ec-85b5-5ae26c154b46')
// Add whatever you want to add to this button element, e.g. add onClick() or submit() or something else which I am not sure of
```

We can see image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oG5w.png

[image]

In such case where `<button>` is providing link click functionality. I can not view and edit `onClick()` or `submit()` etc as its webpack generated javascript. I can only run my javascript code after loading of that webapge in `devtools console`.

How can I disable opening new tab or new window of browser in such case? Or What javascript code should I run to override `<button>` link behaviour?

Comment: `return false` in event handler ?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169198/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-open-in-new-tab-option-for-hyperlinks).

Comment: I think OP wants to disable opening new tab/window, not prevent the click @DominikMatis

Comment: Is there at least any pattern (like a specific element with at least one specific attribute) from which one could recognize such a trigger / such an element?

Comment: @PeterSeliger: I am not sure, I have added screenshot and edited question

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor ... ok, we have a button with an invalid `id`entifier and a `className` value one most probably can also not rely on. The plan is to globally listen to `'click'` events and for any button-click to immediately stop the propagation. Does such radical approach effect any other `button` triggered behavior?

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor ... Another approach is to wrap a function around `window.open` providing additional logic which does intercept and analyze every single invocation of `open`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger: Thanks for these clues to try :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the webpack based code does manage the tab handling of resources one possible solution was to wrap own code around `window.open` or even entirely replace it with an own implementation.

As for the wrapping, based on the intercepted data, one could decide of whether one does suppress the url-handling entirely or, instead of opening a new tab/window, does a forwarding to `location.href` or even proceed with invoking the original `window.open`.

```js
// untouchable 3rd party code
//
function alienLocationHandler({ currentTarget }) {
  let { url, target } = currentTarget.dataset;

  url = (url ?? '').trim();
  if (url) {

    target = (target ?? '').trim();
    if (target) {

      // due to SO's permission handling ...
      //
      // ... Blocked opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/' in a
      // new window because the request was made in a sandboxed
      // frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.
      //
      window.open(url, target);
    } else {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  }
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-url]')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', alienLocationHandler)
  );


// one possible approach :: wrap around `window.open`
//
window.open = (function createAroundHandler(proceed, thisArg) {
  return function aroundWindowOpen(url, target, ...rest) {

    console.log('aroundWindowOpen ...', {
      url,
      target,
      rest,
    });

    // - of cause all the code is just for demonstration purpose.
    //
    // - the OP has to come up with own handler logic which does
    //   fit the OP's needs best.
    
    if (url !== 'https://stackoverflow.com') {

      // invocation of the original `window.open`
      // will be blocked by SO's permission handling.

      proceed.call(thisArg, url, target, ...rest);

    } else {
      // delayed fowarding to `location.href`.

      setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = url }, 5000);
    }
  };
}(window.open, window));
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 87%; top: auto; }
```

```html
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">
  no interception
</button>

<button
  data-url="https://google.com"
  data-target='google'
  >
  intercepted &amp; open attempt  
</button>

<button
  id="_653cde4c-1620-11ec-85b5-5ae26c154b46"
  data-url="https://stackoverflow.com"
  data-target='_blank'
  >
  intercepted and forwarded with 5sec delay
</button>
```

Another approach was to make use of [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) by listening to and handling `click` events at e.g. `document.body` level.

```js
// untouchable 3rd party code
//
function alienLocationHandler({ currentTarget }) {
  let { url, target } = currentTarget.dataset;

  url = (url ?? '').trim();
  if (url) {

    target = (target ?? '').trim();
    if (target) {

      // due to SO's permission handling ...
      //
      // ... Blocked opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/' in a
      // new window because the request was made in a sandboxed
      // frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.
      //
      window.open(url, target);
    } else {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  }
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-url]')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', alienLocationHandler)
  );


// another possible approach :: event delegation
//
// - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation]
// - [https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate]
//
// - [https://javascript.info/event-delegation]
// - [https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/]
//
function isButtonEvent(activeElement, targetNode) {
  return (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') && (
    activeElement.isSameNode(targetNode) ||
    activeElement.contains(targetNode)
  );
}
function preventSpecificButtonClickBehavior(evt) {
  const elmButton = document.activeElement;

  if (isButtonEvent(elmButton, evt.target)) {
    const url = (elmButton.dataset.url ?? '').trim();

    const isUrlBasedPrevented = (url !== 'https://stackoverflow.com');
    const isIdBasedPrevented = ((elmButton.id ?? '').trim() !== '');

    if (isUrlBasedPrevented || isIdBasedPrevented) {
      evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      evt.stopPropagation();

      if (isUrlBasedPrevented) {
        console.log('prevented button click behavior ... URL based')
      }
      if (isIdBasedPrevented) {
        console.log('prevented button click behavior ... ID based')
      }
    }
  }
}
document
  .body
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    preventSpecificButtonClickBehavior,
    // - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters]
    // - The boolean `useCapture` parameter/flag does the trick if set as `true` value.
    true
  );
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 87%; top: auto; }
```

```html
<button data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">
  click behavior not prevented
</button>

<button
  id="_653cde4c-1620-11ec-85b5-5ae26c154b46"
  data-url="https://stackoverflow.com"
  >
  prevented behavior (id based)
</button>

<button
  data-url="https://google.com"
  data-target='google'
  >
  <span>
    <span>
      prevented behavior (url based)
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor ... are there any questions left regarding both above provided approaches?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. This answer gave me clues to build approch to solve my problem. I have up voted your answer. Can your approch help my problem where I dont have `data-url` in `<button>`. please see screenshot

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor ...I suppose you talk about the event delegation based approach. The `data-*` attributes where only for demonstration purposes in order to mimic the third-party button-click triggered hyperlink-behavior. Thus you need to figure out yourself how to best identify the event source that then has to be stopped with propagating the event any further. A viable identification might already be the check for the special pattern of a button's `id`' in combination with the structure of such a button, like there is always a `<div/>` with another `id` attribute embedded within a `<button/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the logic in the `onClick()` does something like `window.open(url, [params])`. You can change this to setting `window.location.href = url;` and the url will be loaded in the same window.

Comment: We don't know value of `url`

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor `url` is the URL to which you are going when clicked

Comment: for external website I dont have access to view and edit onClick(). I can only run my javascript code on top of that webapge after its loading in devtools console.